# Find on custom object

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I provide a function object, `find_name`, to search for specific object matching a `name`, but it turns out I'm doing something wrong:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Item
{
    Item() : name(), id(), value() { }
    Item(std::string n, int i, double v) : name(n), id(i), value(v) { }
    Item(const Item& src) : name(src.name), id(src.id), value(src.value) { }

    Item& operator= (const Item& src)
    {
       Item temp(src);
       swap(temp);
       return *this;
    }

    void swap(Item& src)
    {
       std::swap(src.name, name);
       std::swap(src.id, id);
       std::swap(src.value, value);
    }

std::string name;
int id;
double value;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

void swap(Item& lhs, Item& rhs) { lhs.swap(rhs); }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

struct find_name 
{
    find_name(const std::string& t) : target(t) { }
    bool operator() (const Item& src) const { return src.name == target; }

    std::string target;
};

//--------------------------------------------------------------------


void erase (std::vector<Item>& v, const std::string& name)
{
    std::vector<Item>::iterator found = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), find_name(name));
    //std::vector<Item>::iterator found = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), [name] (const Item& src) { return src.name  == name; });

    if (found != v.end())
    {
        v.erase(found);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout <<"\nName: "<< name <<" not found!\n";
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------- 


int main() 
{
    std::vector<Item> items;
    items.push_back(Item("horse shoe", 99, 12.34));

    std::string name("horse shoe");
    erase(items, name);

    return 0;
}
```

What's the problem in the `find` function?

---

As requested: Error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of ‘bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Value = const find_name]’:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const find_name>]’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from ‘_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const find_name>]’
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algo.h:3792:28:   required from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item> >; _Tp = find_name]’
prog.cpp:77:83:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h:199:17: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘Item’ and ‘const find_name’)
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:856:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:856:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h:199:17: note:   ‘Item’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>’
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:863:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_iterator.h:863:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h:199:17: note:   ‘Item’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>’
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/6/bits/c++allocator.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/string:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note: candidate: template<class _Tp> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)
     operator==(const new_allocator<_Tp>&, const new_allocator<_Tp>&)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6/ext/new_allocator.h:139:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/6/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/predefined_ops.h:199:17: note:   ‘Item’ is not derived from ‘const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>’
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
           ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

[Live sample here](https://ideone.com/fI2P70)

Comment: What happens when you compile and run your code? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they? If not, what is the output and how does it differ from what you want?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I've provided a link at the end. Is it working?

Comment: Please show the output here directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is to find a *value*. To provide a predicate you must use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).